# Is "on" in "spend sth on doing sth" optional?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Cambridge dictionary gives this example

> We've just spent $1.9 million **on improving** our computer network.

I am aware of that usage, in the standard form, `spend sth on doing sth`.

This post (https://www.buzzfeed.com/eleanorjones/how-i-fell-back-in-love-with-swimming-and-my-body) starts with

> After over a decade **spent avoiding** pools, swimsuits, and public showers, I've found my way back to the water and all the reasons I loved it as a child.

I guess that means the author spent a lot time (over a decade) on avoiding swimming, is my understanding right? In other words, is "spend on doing" a contraction form of "spend time on doing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot omit the "time" argument. *But* you don't have to use the word *time*: you can use a period of time.

In this case the "time" spent is *a decade*. The writer *spent a decade avoiding pools etc*; but they turned it round to make the decade the subject, and relegate the rest to a reduced relative clause:

> ... a decade [that was] spent avoiding pools ...

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you. I just updated my OP, where the 1st example uses "on doing". It seems that the "on" is optional, right?

Comment: The word "on" is indeed optional. The "on" argument (whether time, money, effort, etc) is not.